# What is the "t=" query parameter in a socket.io handshake

Tags: node.js, socket.io, long-polling

A socketIO handshake looks something like this :

`http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M5eHk0h`

What is the `t` parameter? Can't find a explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the `timestampParam` from [engine.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client). Its value is a Unique ID generated using the npm package [`yeast`](https://npmjs.com/package/yeast).

This is referenced in the API docs under the Socket Constructor Options (docs below). [If no value is given to `timestampParam` when creating a new instance of a Socket, the parameter name is switched to `t`](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client/blob/42501c658e98f69cdb1194d5222b003c6cfc0967/lib/socket.js#L69) and assigned a value from `yeast()`. You can see this in the source for  on [Line 223 of lib/transports/polling.js](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client/blob/7aad0d6da1ee9941002b44d0b6700e0b71d21151/lib/transports/polling.js#L223)

> [Socket constructor() Options](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client#methods)
>
> - `timestampParam` (`String`): timestamp parameter (`t`)

To clarify where `engine.io-client` comes into play, it is a dependency of `socket.io-client` which, `socket.io` depends on. `engine.io` provides the actual communication layer implementation which `socket.io` is built upon. `engine.io-client` is the client portion of `engine.io`.

#### Why does socket.io use `t`?

As [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) pointed out in the comments, `t` is used for cache busting. Cache busting, is a technique that prevents the browser from serving a cached resource  instead of requesting the resource.

Socket.io implements cache busting with a timestamp parameter in the query string. If you assign `timestampParam` a value of `ts` then the key for the timestamp would be `ts`, it defaults to `t` if no value is assigned. By assigning this parameter a unique value created with `yeast` on every poll to the server, Socket.io is able to always retrieve the latest data from the server and circumvent the cache. Since polling transports would not work as expected without cache busting, timestamping is enabled by default and must be explicitly disabled.

AFAIK, the Socket.io server does not utilize the timestamp parameter for anything other than cache busting.

**More about `yeast()`**

`yeast()` guarantees a compressed unique ID specifically for cache busting. The [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yeast) gives us some more detailed information on how `yeast()` works.

> Yeast is a unique id generator. It has been primarily designed to generate a unique id which can be used for cache busting. A common practice for this is to use a timestamp, but there are couple of downsides when using timestamps.
>
> 1. The timestamp is already 13 chars long. This might not matter for 1 request but if you make hundreds of them this quickly adds up in bandwidth and processing time.
> 2. It's not unique enough. If you generate two stamps right after each other, they would be identical because the timing accuracy is limited to milliseconds.
>
> Yeast solves both of these issues by:
>
> 1. Compressing the generated timestamp using a custom `encode()` function that returns a string representation of the number.
> 2. Seeding the id in case of collision (when the id is identical to the previous one).
>
> To keep the strings unique it will use the `.` char to separate the generated stamp from the seed.

Comment: Shouldn't you explain that this appears to be done for cache busting reasons only.  Does the server actually use this value?

Comment: @jfriend00, updated the answer to include explanation of cache busting and role of `yeast()` when using timestamps on polling transports.

Comment: Now, a most excellent answer!  Before you wrote your answer, I tried to find the relevant code on Github and could not find it.  The way socket.io is structured with so many modules and the separation between engine.io and socket.io, it is NOT easy to find things in that code base.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks. Yeah, I think the implementation of the socket.io is broken up across nearly a dozen repositories. It was a challenge finding where `t` was being accessed. Considering it is aliased as `this.timestampParam` and is only every referenced as the default assignment when initializing `this.timestampParam`. After that `this.timestampParam` is only referenced again when assigning the query string the value of `t`.

Comment: Thanx for taking the time to answer! Great answer as well.